# WPF ListBox DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you bind a value and a key to a listbox using Linq To Sql?

I am populating a listbox using linq to sql class, here is the WPF:

```
<ListBox  Name="listBox1" Loaded="listBox1_Loaded" />
```

And the following displays the `FullName`s but not the `Case_Number`:

```
using (ToolboxDataContext toolboxDB = new ToolboxDataContext())
{
    var x = toolboxDB.DropDownIndividuals().ToList(); 
    listBox1.ItemsSource = x;
}
```

I also tried this and did not work:

```
foreach (var y in x)
{
    listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = y.FullName.ToString() ;
    listBox1.SelectedValuePath = y.Case_Number.ToString() ;
    // Console.WriteLine(y.Case_Number.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the mark-up you can specify the types to bind to, such as:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="Case_Number"/>
```

Comment: Nice. Now I did       private void listBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

In XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" 
         DisplayMemberPath="FullName" 
         SelectedValuePath="Case_Number" />
```

In code behind:

```
using (ToolboxDataContext toolboxDB = new ToolboxDataContext())
     PersonsListBox.ItemsSource = toolboxDB.DropDownIndividuals().ToList();
```